# Not being able to establish connection for In app billing in android

Tags: android, google-analytics, in-app-billing

I am trying to integrate In app billing v3 in my app. I call the following function to initialize.

```
public static void SetupInappBilling()
{
    mHelper = new IabHelper(context, base64EncodedPublicKey);
    mHelper.enableDebugLogging(true);
    mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() 
    {
        public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) 
        {
            if (result.isSuccess())
            {
                Log.e("tag", "connected");
                ConnectionEstablished = true;

            } 
            else
            {
                    Log.e("tag", "not connected");

                    ConnectionEstablished = false;
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

but i dont get call back in **OnIabSetupFinishedListener**
Can anyone tell me how to fix this issue

Comment: How do you conclude that a Warning about Google Analytics relates to you not receiving an in-app billing event?

Comment: Because i was not getting them before i started implementing in app billing and i have not explicitly called google analytics anywhere in my application

Comment: Google Analytics is not involved in IAB as far as I know/have observed. Either way, please see it independently. -- But you _do_ call _SetupInappBilling()_? And in what Thread and Context do you do that?

Comment: I call SetupInappBilling() from OnCreate() function

Comment: And the device has connectivity? And there are no messages which _really_ relate to the IAB? The IAB will not work under certain conditions. Do you check the return value of _startSetup()_? I'm willing to bet you can't connect to the service even.

Comment: I have internet connectivity and have INTERNET permission. I am not getting call back to listner given in startSetup().

Comment: But what about the return value of _startSetup()_? According to the code, you ignore it. It will fail e.g. if you're running on a regular AVD or if no Google Play account is set up.

Comment: I am running on a device and return type of startSetup() is void. The only log i get related to IAB is `02-18 17:07:54.248: D/IabHelper(6862): Starting in-app billing setup.`

Comment: I'm sorry. You're right. -- Umm, the example implementation ***** is somewhat incomplete. I highly recommend checking the boolean result of the _bindService()_ call at the end of _IabHelper.startSetup()_. You could return that as the result of startSetup() for example. If it's false, the bind operation failed and no callbacks will ever get called.

Comment: boolean result of the bindService() is false. Any idea on what might be going wrong.

Comment: That's what I thought. Please see my answer. I would suspect that your device doesn't support IAB V3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed, the example `IabHelper` implementation ignores the return value of the `bindService()` call.

`bindService()` returns `false` if it cannot bind to the Service. In this case, no callbacks will ever get called. In this respect, the return value of `bindService()` is essential for the program logic and should never be ignored; the example application is not exactly perfect here.

If I recall this correctly, conditions where binding to the IAB V3 will not work are:

- Only IAB V2 is available (it uses a different class name)
- Google Play is not fully set up

Comment: The problem was with my google play version being old. Thank you