# How to access Google Play Android Developer API through backend server

Tags: php, android, google-api, google-play-services, google-api-php-client

I am implemented In App Billing for android.I wanted to implement subscription validity checking through my backend server. As Google Play Documentation, for making call for Google Play API,need authentication using oauth 2.0.

I followed instructions for registering project and creating credentials. But from there I have no idea how to use those credentials, I tried authentication via CURL request, but it asking permission as shown in follwing image[image]

This permissions works fine I can exchange code and get access token, but all this done by manually, how should I implement this on backend.
I even try to use google api php library provided by Google, but It adds confusion. Also they didn't provide any example, how to use library.

Can anybody elaborate how exactly use library or pure php?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To perform LVL and/or IAB validation on a server, do not access Google servers directly from the server. Even if all information were available, you would face integrity problems, because your app and your server will see different information due to synchronization latencies.

Instead, [use your app as a proxy and validate the Google Play information on your server as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16030386/1856738).

Comment: So,you suggesting get subscription information like expiration date via android application and then validate with backend server?

Comment: Absolutely. Key only on server, signature validation on server. For IAB, re-play attacks are possible in general so the question is, what kind of items are those. But since they cannot be refunded, the purchase is still authentic, so you'll only have to track consumption on the server to avoid a re-play attack.

Comment: But, if I am using Subscription model which expires with every month, I still need to check renewal of subscription, for that matter, I need to use Google Play Services right? So for that I have to access Google API's?

Comment: I don't think so. You'll have your app ask for subscription validation via the IAB V3 API [as described here](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html#Subs) and GP will not deliver expired subscriptions as a result. YOu send that response to your server for validation just like any other IAB information.