# Unique String In-App Purchase on Android

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

In [Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/purchase-iab-products.html#Purchase) there is this recommendation:

> **Security Recommendation**: It’s good practice to pass in a string that
>   helps your application to identify the user who made the purchase, so
>   that you can later verify that this is a legitimate purchase by that
>   user. For consumable items, you can use a randomly generated string,
>   but for non-consumable items you should use a string that uniquely
>   identifies the user.

What are the best practices to generate this string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the app is on its own, the best approach is to

- use the obfuscated Google Play LVL user id and, after a separator
- add a secure random information (aka nonce) and, depending on your needs,
- you can add additional info identifying e.g. the point in time

This way, you can

- associate LVL and IAB information and
- the IAB service responses are a bit more secure than they would be without the nonce

The following vulnerabilities remain:

- [Having your app check LVL/IAB is insecure in general](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2010/09/securing-android-lvl-applications.html) because the checks can in principle be overridden after reverse engineering.
- With the IAB nonce being set upon *creation of the buy intent* (rather than upon the validity request itself), there's no way to validate that the response you get does not come from a re-play attack.
- The [IAB V3 information is cached inside the IAB service on the Android device](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14830007/1856738), so it's not even guaranteed that you'll get the latest information; the service will silently pass cached information to the app if the device is offline or the service decides that the validity of the cached information needs not be re-validated right now.

The only way to further improve security is to [use a server-based approach for LVL/IAB validation.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16030386/1856738)

Comment: Sorry, I don't fully understand the answer. Are we talking about in-app purchases? What does LVL has to do with in-app purchases?

Comment: @mneri I suggest using LVL information for the IAB developer payload. Also, I compare IAB security to LVL security. If you don't use LVL, then you can't have a requirement to associate LVL and IAB information so just don't use the LVL user info for the IAB developer payload.