# In-app billing testing using different google account

Tags: android, in-app-billing

To test in app billing, it is said that i need to do a **factory reset**
 and then specify my test account when the device boots up.

I have configured 2 Google accounts and can i somehow get the test account to be active for the transactions and then revert back to the original when i am done with the in-app billing testing ?

I am not able to understand the need for factory reset to test in-app billing when i can set multiple Google accounts.

Comment: It might be that the IAB fails to update its cache when you switch between accounts during operation. The IAB [uses extensive caching internally](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14830007/1856738). But no matter what the reason is, I haven't found a way to overcome this restriction so far.

Answer (score 0):

After looking around the factory reset is currently the only way to change the device account.
There is a [issue](https://code.google.com/p/marketbilling/issues/detail?id=24) for this problem on Android Market In-App Billing

I'm guessing you cant use the personal account because it is the same as the developer console account (which Google doesn't allow). However, if you are using a personal account on the device you could [change the developer console account](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/139626?hl=en).

This then means that you could test with your personal account avoiding factory resets.